# How type inference works in Java or why mockito even compile

Tags: java, generics

Trying to [fix method resolution in standalone java parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525028/symbols-resolution-in-standalone-intellij-parser) I found [a code in mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/test/java/org/mockitousage/matchers/MoreMatchersTest.java#L36) which I don't understand. And if I'm creating small test based on mockito code:

```
package org.mockitousage.matchers;

import java.util.Collection;

public class MoreMatchersTest {
    public interface IMethods {
        String simpleMethod(String argument);
        String simpleMethod(Collection<?> collection);
        String simpleMethod(Object argument);
    }

    private IMethods mock;

    public static <T> T any() {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> T verify(T m) {
        return m;
    }

    public void any_should_be_actual_alias_to_anyObject() {
        verify(mock).simpleMethod(any());
    }
}
```

I'm getting compilation error as I expect:

```
Error:(23, 21) java: reference to simpleMethod is ambiguous
  both method simpleMethod(java.lang.String) in org.mockitousage.matchers.MoreMatchersTest.IMethods and method simpleMethod(java.util.Collection<?>) in org.mockitousage.matchers.MoreMatchersTest.IMethods match
```

But somehow mockito compiles successfully. Could you explain me please why code in mockito compiles (and which specialization of `<T>any` compiler choosing) or how to modify my sample so it will compile too (I understand that I could cast `any()` to specific type or remove overloads of `simpleMethod` but I want to be as close to mockito code as possible).

Command line output:

```
> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_111

> javac -d C:\w\MockitoTest\out\production\MockitoTest -classpath C:\w\MockitoTest\out\production\MockitoTest -sourcepath C:\w\MockitoTest\src -g -source 8 -target 8 C:\w\MockitoTest\src\org\mockitousage\matchers\MoreMatchersTest.java
C:\w\MockitoTest\src\org\mockitousage\matchers\MoreMatchersTest.java:23: error: reference to simpleMethod is ambiguous
        verify(mock).simpleMethod(any());
                    ^
  both method simpleMethod(String) in IMethods and method simpleMethod(Collection<?>) in IMethods match
1 error

> javac -d C:\w\MockitoTest\out\production\MockitoTest -classpath C:\w\MockitoTest\out\production\MockitoTest -sourcepath C:\w\MockitoTest\src -g -source 7 -target 7 C:\w\MockitoTest\src\org\mockitousage\matchers\MoreMatchersTest.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
```

Comment: "Could you explain me please why code in mockito compile" which code are you referring to? The code is not the same as yours.

Comment: @peter-lawrey I know that, but I'm trying to understand what the difference between mockito code and this extract from mockito code.

Comment: your code works (I mean compiles) for me on Java 7. Compiler is choosing `String simpleMethod(Object argument);` for any argument, which is kind of expected. Which version of Java do you have?

Comment: @peter-lawrey Well, I could not post all mockito code in question, so I created sample with only relevant code from it, but obviously I'm missing something

Comment: @borys-zibrov Java 8, and mockito code compiles with java 8 too. And yes - when I go to method in idea (in both my test and mockito) jumps to variant with Object - but why is it expected?

Comment: well, type inference in Java 8 got overhaul, and a chapter in JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html. Before Java 8,  inferred type would have been Object, but seems like it's more complicated at version 8

Comment: see also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload

Comment: @borys-zibrov yes, it is compiling with java 8 when I specify project language level as java 7 in idea and failing when it is java 8. Reading your links and trying to make sense of it.

Comment: for this issue I think you need to specify exactly jdk vendor / version / build. better build it with maven/gradle, without intellij to sort out IDE issues from jdk issues

Comment: @borys-zibrov I've added javac output from oracle jdk 8 update 111

Comment: thanks, I will do my best to understand what goes on :)

Comment: @ISanych, which version of Mockito do you use? I bet it's the one compiled for java 6 or 7, not java 8

Comment: @borys-zibrov - I'm using version from git master, but you right - mockito_main & mockito_test modules are using Java 6 language level (all other modules and project itself uses Java 8 and I only checked project itself before) - Could you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to begin with the beginning, Java 8 defined type inference rules described in details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), so that some code that compiles happily under 1.7 or 1.6 doesn't compile any longer under 1.8, for instance the example code won't compile indeed:

```
public class MoreMatchersTest {
    public interface IMethods {
        String simpleMethod(String argument);
        String simpleMethod(Collection<?> collection);
        String simpleMethod(Object argument);
    }

    private IMethods mock;

    public static <T> T any() {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> T verify(T m) {
        return m;
    }

    public void any_should_be_actual_alias_to_anyObject() {
        verify(mock).simpleMethod(any());
    }
}
```

There are multiple questions about that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020493/why-is-this-method-overloading-ambiguous) for example.

So the question was why Mockito seemed to work, and the answer was rather simple. Mockito 2.x releases are compiled with `targetCompatibility = 1.6` ([github](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/build.gradle)), and even Mockito on master uses language level 1.6 for some modules.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the type as the compiler binds to Object in this case.

This line

```
 verify(mock).simpleMethod(any()); // bind to simpleMethod(Object)
```

It compiles fine (both mockito and your example) for me with Java 8 update 101.

Comment: yes, it should work, I agree. There's no magic going on in Mockito. @iSanych, perhaps a bug in your JDK? try the latest from Oracle.

Comment: it is compiling with java 8 when I specify project language level as java 7 in idea and failing when it is java 8. Yes, I know where it is resolving I'm trying to understand why

Comment: @borys-zibrov I doubt that it is jdk bug, maybe idea runs it with some options - trying to get full log how idea runs java. and the same jdk with java level 8 compiles mockito without errors. I only have issues in method resolution when trying to use standalone idea parser.

Comment: added command line output for java 8 compiler with target 7 & 8

Comment: @ISanych I added this class to the mockito repo and it compiles fine. Copy it into a project by itself and it gets the error you see.

Comment: so maybe mockito was compiled with target compatibility of 1.6 or 1.7?